# Rust borrow checker analogy

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

Being a novice C++ programmer learning Rust, I am not fully comfortable with ownership and how the borrow checker works, so while experimenting with it, I've come to an analogy that I wanted to inquire about. Could I think of rusts' transfer of ownership as the compiler inserting a free immediately after any function call that borrows any heap-allocated value, as an example:

```
analogy(Type* val) {
...
}

function() {
    Type* arg = new Type()
    analogy(arg)

// Could I think of the borrow checker on assumption
// as a preprocessor that inserts the following

    delete arg 

// After doing so, a static analyzer is run by the compiler
// which can trivially detect an error such as this

    print(arg)
}
```

Comment: Don't tag your question with ```C```, ```C++``` when there is no code related to them.

Comment: If you learned to use `new` from your book, please get another one. Contemporary C++ code does not use `new`.

Comment: No, the borrow checker works at compile time. I don't believe it generates code that runs at execution time. Maybe a better analogy would be to think of it as a very strict peer reviewer that only focuses on who owns the values of variables.

Comment: Also in general, do not try to map concepts from one language 1-1 to another language.  Different languages is different rules. First learn BOTH languages and how they behave before even considering transferring concepts.

Comment: @aled If that's the case (checks at compile time) then OP needs to learn meta (template) programming or extensions to the compiler (llvm), which are not exactly beginner topics either.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Oh, thank you for the comment, I am new to posting on StackOverflow, and missed that convention. I removed the unrelated tags.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I mean, it simplifies things though, doesn't it? I'm not looking for an exact 1-1 example, I understand I might shoot my foot by assuming that they act exactly alike; that's why I'm asking on StackOverflow if there are any differences. I suppose I just want a frame of reference. I appreciate the comment though!

Comment: **As an oversimplified mental model**, you can map C++ to Rust the following way: Rust uses const by default and move semantics by default (with hard compile time errors when using moved from objects), while C++ has mutable by default and utilizes copy semantics by default. EDIT: but I agree with @PepijnKramer mapping mechanisms between languages is not necessarily a good idea, especially when being a novice.

Comment: @aled oh I'm not inferring that it does that on execution. I just assumed it would happen once at compile time, and I understand that it's not as simple as code-generation. But what differences would there be though? Please bear with me, as I mentioned I am a beginner. and thank you for your comment.

Comment: Please post the Rust signature that you imagine for `analogy()`. Does it take `Type`? `&Type`? It's not clear to me what you meant.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah, I actually just meant it as a pseudo-code example, and due to my lack of experience in writing Rust, I used C/C++ notions to represent what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is *already* an analogy in the standard library: instead of compile-time borrow-checking, you can use run-time borrow-checking with `RefCell` (single-threaded) or `RwLock` (multi-threaded).

We can thus convert an example by using [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), try it [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1edda13d541cb879a653047f7cc6731a):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub fn original() {
    let mut x = String::from("Hello, world!");

    let y = &x;

    //  x.push('!');  //  Borrow-checking error.

    println!("{y:?}");

    x.push('!');

    println!("{x:?}");
}

pub fn converted() {
    let x = RefCell::new(String::from("Hello, world!"));

    let y = x.borrow();

    //  x.borrow_mut().push('!');  //  Panic.

    println!("{y:?}");

    x.borrow_mut().push('!');

    println!("{x:?}");
}
```

Hence, rather than a temporary "delete", it's best to think of borrowing as read-write locking:

- `&T` locks for *reads*, and multiple readers are allowed, but no writer is.
- `&mut T` locks for *writes*, no other reader nor writer is allowed.

Comment: Oh that's actually really cool! I will definitely try to learn more about the borrow checker using it! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @العوين: Take it easy! Borrow-checking is a pretty unique concept amongst mainstream programming languages, and as all first-time exposures it can take a while to grok. As soon as you have 50 points of reputation, you can hop on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust to chat or otherwise don't hesitate to check the Rust Community Discord Server, for more informal discussions.

Answer (score 1):

The following explanation is a simplified model but it should get you started. `new` and `delete` are opposites, just like `{` and `}` are. It's best to think about it with lots of braces where the opening brace resembles the introduction of a fresh variable and possibly `new`. The closing brace represents the end of the variable's life time and possibly `delete`:

```
{
    Foo x = new ...;

    {
        Foo y = &x; // y's introduction lacks 'new'
        bar(y);     // function calls do not imply 'new'
        // so no 'delete' here
    }
    // y is inaccessible here without extending the closing brace

    bar(x);
    print(x);

    delete x;
}
// x is inaccessible here
```